# detect user agent with javascript then execute action if not mobile

Tags: mobile, detect, agent

I designed my site to first serve mobile devices but if the user agent is a desktop, I wanted to run a script. I came up with the following script but it is not working. The idea is to run the horizontalview() function if none of the variables match.

```
function view() {
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var checker = {
    iphone: ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/),
    blackberry: ua.match(/BlackBerry/),
    android: ua.match(/Android/)
};
if (checker.iphone);
{}
if (checker.blackberry);
{}
if (checker.android);
{}
else
{
horizontalview();
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I omitted semi-colons after brackets on the following snippet from my previous example.

```
if (checker.iphone)
{}
if (checker.blackberry)
{}
if (checker.android)
{}
```